# Can I add Links as favorites to TFS 2012 Team Site?

Tags: tfs, tfs-web-access

I have a TFS 2012 Team site specifically for TFS Management. I would like to place template links for creating work items on the site so that team leads may create work items for me to add users or otherwise modify permissions.

I created the templates by the "Copy template URL" (a great feature btw), and then sent this as an email to my stakeholders.

[image]

I think it is better to have this link easily available from my team site. Are there any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what you mean by team site.  There is the TFS Web Access page, and then there is the optional Team Project Portal (in SharePoint).

If you are using the Portal in SharePoint then you can add a links webpart to any page within the site.

If you are talking about the TFS Web Access page, then I don't think there is currently any supported method to customize the home page to add arbitrary links.

Comment: I'm referring to the new Team Site features, which are part of TWA in TFS 2012.

Comment: TFSWA does not support customizations at this time.